# Provident fund Module in ODOO 8 with complete workflow

Tags: odoo-8

Is there any module which can handle the complete flow of Provident Fund in ODOO 8?
I searched a lot and I just found 1 module which is in Openerp7.0.

Answer (score 0):

There exist no such module which can handle complete work flow of Provident fund.

In V7 there is a module which include just the values of Provident fund but thats also does not handle the complete work flow.

For this you have to code a lot.